# FileNotFound even though File does exist

Tags: file, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception, readfile

Excuse me for the sloppy code, it is just a test project and I've been working on this bug for at least a week now

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Report> report =  new ArrayList<Report>();
    Report test = new Report();
    File file = new File("testByte.txt");
    Scanner inputFile;
    try {
        inputFile = new Scanner(new File("port.txt"));

        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
                test.LoadFromFile(inputFile);
                report.add(test);   
        }

        inputFile.close();


        PdfMaker pdf = new PdfMaker(report);

        try {
            pdf.createLog();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    try
    {
        boolean check = true;
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        for(int i = 0; i < report.size(); i++)
        {
            report.get(i).WriteToFile(output, check);
            check = false;
        }

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I get the file not found error on the line

FileNotFoundException(Throwable).(String) line: 264

```
inputFile = new Scanner(new File("port.txt");
```

I've checked the properties of the file and everything checks out to be okay

It is located in the appropriate folder

The source path does have the workbench folder as a path.

If anyone could point me in the direction to fix this problem, it would be very helpful since I've wasted hours searching for the internet.

*I bet it is something easy and I'm just to blind to see it

Comment: What do you mean with "appropriate folder"? From which directory you execute the program? Where is your file? Same dir as where you start the program?

Comment: BY appropriate folder I meant the default folder for the dir, where the project is located